# eclipse java project .class path reference ssue

Tags: java, build, javafx

I imported a javaFX project to eclipse Helios. It is throwing out the below error.

"The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.util.function.Function"

I had tried all the possible solutions like

Restarting eclipse 
Cleaning the project
Uninstalling all other jres except jre1.8 as javafx is supported only by jre 1.8
Removing and adding jre 1.8
removing the unnecessary lines from .classpath

Still the same error is seen in my eclipse. Could somebody help me out in resolving this

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked the Compiler compliance level? (right-click the project, Properties... -> Java Compiler)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Helios is from 2010. You should probably use a newer version. You will also need a JDK if you want to compile ...

Comment: Hi Nikos, java compiler compliance is 1.6. I hope there is no need to upgrade it. Isn't it?

Comment: With eclipse Java EE IDE also I have the same issue